# Múltiplas requisições com ajax - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, for

Tenho uma página contendo 1 (uma) a 50 requisições. Então uso um loop que faz a chamada.

Pela velocidade de minha internet, em questão de 3 segundos deveria carregar todas as requisições. Mas é feito uma a uma, daí demora minutos para finalizar.

Como faço para lançar todas essas requisições de uma só vez?

Obs: O resultado pode ser dado após o retorno de cada uma, não no todo.

```
for(var obj in value){
   $.ajax({
       method:"POST",
       url : "tracker/correios-xml.php",
       data : {cod_correios: e.dados.e_tracking_number, c_retorno : class_add},
       dataType : "json",
       error: function(request, status, erro){

       },
       success: function(e, status, request){

       }
   });
}
```

Comment: Creio não ser possível, já que cada requisição possui valores próprios, imagino que devem ser feitas de forma individual.

Comment: @dvd Então, eu adiciono o ID(número) da div e envio e trago ele de volta, daí eu sei onde adicionar cada parte, independente da posição que ele esteja. Eu gostaria de enviar tudo de uma só vez, daí de acordo com que ia retornando eu jogava os valores para as respectivas divs... mas da forma que está indo, ele vai uma por vez... digamos, não carrega a última, pois ainda tem a antipenúltima que não retornou...

Comment: As requesições ajax como tens na pergunta não têm relação umas com as outras. Não vejo nada aí que as faça esperar umas pelas outras.

Comment: @Sergio Entendo, então é normal ser lento assim... Pois hoje verificando, percebi que algumas raras carregam na frente de outras. Eu esperava que pela velocidade da internet desse para carregar todos de uma só vez. Como é lento, eu acabei mudando o sistema para carregar apenas quando o elemento fica visível, daí evito, acredito sobrecarregar menos o servidor, pois em cada venda tenho que chamar umas 5 requisições diferentes... ATT